# custom finder with matching in association definition?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have two models: Contacts and Groups with belongsToMany association.

I want to get only that groups what is accessible for the contact. For this I have a custom finder.

```
public function findAccessible(Query $query, array $options){
    return $query
            ->where(['admin_user_id' => $options['User.id']])
            ->orWhere(['public' => true])
            ->matching('Users', function($q) use ($options){
                return $q->orWhere(['Users.id' => $options['User.id']]);
            });
}
```

So I can call to following and I will get what I want.

```
$accessibleGroups = $this->Contacts->Groups->find('accessible', ['User.id' => $this->Auth->user('id')]);
```

But if I have a contain, than it will give back all groups not just accessible ones.

```
$contact = $this->Contacts->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Groups']
    ]);
```

How to limit the contain to accessible?

I can not add the custom finder to the table association definition's finder property, as I can not pass the $options there. Or can I?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me quote the docs and the tests (if you can't find something in the docs, the tests are often a useful source for information on how to do things).

**http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#passing-conditions-to-contain**

> If you have defined some custom finder methods in your associated table, you can use them inside contain:
>
> ```php
> // Bring all articles, but only bring the comments that are approved and
> // popular.
> $query = $articles->find()->contain([
>     'Comments' => function ($q) {
>        return $q->find('approved')->find('popular');
>     }
> ]);
> ```

In that scenario you could simply pass in the conditions in the `find()` call just like you are already doing.

---

**http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#using-the-finder-option**

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/7fc4cfe3ae7d4c523331a44e2862bab5c8f44f1e/tests/TestCase/ORM/QueryTest.php#L2175**

So there's also this "hidden" `finder` option that can be used instead of a callable:

```php
$table->find('all')
    ->where(['Articles.author_id' => $authorId])
    ->contain([
        'Authors' => [
            'finder' => ['byAuthor' => ['author_id' => $authorId]]
        ]
    ]);
```

---

I guess it wouldn't hurt if the finder usage would be documented a little more detailed in the Cookbook, the docblock for `Query::contain()` is missing info about it too.